# Do I need a comma when using multiple adverbs?

Tags: commas

These are two adverbs used together....actually three.

> They were raised very closely together.

Do I need a comma to separate "together"?

> They were raised very closely, together.

The first sentence just does not sound right to my ear. But I am not a native speaker, so I thought it best to ask. Thank you.

Comment: I am not a native speaker either, but the second sounds rather artificial, although it is possible to say it that way, with a pause after 'closely'.  The two sentences do have slightly different meanings.

Comment: Btw there is nothing wrong with the _bare adverb_ "close". In fact, it's more idiomatic and natural-sounding in your example. The idea that all adverbs have to have the -ly suffix to distinguish them from the adjective form is a myth.

Comment: In addition, the adverb *very* is overused. And I don't see how *together* adds much. Thus, taking into account Bryan's comment, you could pleasantly restate your sentence as *They were raised close*.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to set off "together", as in some literary context (emphasizing "together"), don't add a comma.

If you speak the two phrases, and pause at the comma, you can probably get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a comma, because *very closely* and *together* are not separate adverbs in this case; instead, *very closely* modifies *together*.

To put it a different way: they were not raised very closely, and together; they were raised *in very close togetherness*.